# FileReader result brings me to a blank page with "about:blank#blocked" in the address bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I'm trying to build a UI that allows users to download files from their computer to display in a playlist. So far all I did was display the name of the file in the list like so

[image]

Just currently I just started to get the links for each li to display different (before they were all the same). But now my functionality is slow and when I click on the link it brings to me to a blank page that has "about:blank#blocked" in the address bar when I want bring up the and play the audio. This is what my state looks like (The links are different):

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class DownloadTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      files: []
    };
  }


handleClick = event => {

  // Helper code to read file and return promise
  const readFile = (file) => {

    const fileList = [];

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    // create the promise and return it
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // if file reader has an error, report it
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject({ error })
      }

      // if success, resolve the promise
      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        resolve({
          name: file.name,
          link: fileReader.result
        })
      }

      // start reading the file
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
    })
  }

  // create all the file reader promises
  // create an array from the files list and use map to generate
  // an array of promises
  const allReaders = Array.from(event.target.files).map(readFile)

  // Now handle the array of promises we just created
  Promise.all(allReaders)
    .then(fileList => {
      console.log(fileList)
      // set the state that we have all the files
      this.setState({ files: fileList });
    })
    .catch(error => { 
       console.error(error)
    });

}

  render() {
     console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="input">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleClick}
          id="upload-file"
          className="inputName"
          type="file"
          multiple
          ref={this.inputRef}
        />
        <div>
          <ul ref={this.ulRef}>
            {this.state.files.map((file, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <a href={file.link} download>{file.name}</a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DownloadTest;
```

Comment: You're reading all the text in the file and assigning that to file.link, then setting file.link as the HREF attribute of your link. In other words, where you're meant to put a URL for the link to go to, you're instead putting the entire contents of the file. That's certainly not correct.

Comment: Do you know how to get the URL?

Comment: Depending on how big the file is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL If the file is quite large, you may need to read it as a Blob first, then create an object URL from that Blob.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: Google is your friend :) Do some research, attempt it yourself, and if you can't get it working, post a new question (or an update to this one) with your new code :)

Comment: My problem was I was using `readAsText()` instead of `readAsDataURL()` but it's still displaying the same link now.

Comment: Never mind the links are actually different.